# Is there a way to use Mako templates for plain-text files where newlines matter?

Tags: python, template-engine, mako, plaintext

In an existing application we are using Mako templates (unfortunately..). That works ok for HTML output since newlines do not matter.

However, we now need to generate a text/plain email using a template - so any newlines introduced by control statements are not acceptable.

Does Mako provide any options to make statement lines (i.e. those starting with `%`) not cause a newline in the output? I checked the docs but couldn't find anything so far...

Comment: Have you looked at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mako-discuss/nEob4D1pVNs ?

Comment: That basically means stripping some of the newlines in the template itself. Would be really ugly and hard to do this with big file-based templates...

Comment: Okay, it was just a pointer, did not really read this through myself..

Answer (score 5):

If you add a backslash at the end of the line like this: "<%   %>\", you can suppress the newline.